# Selecting an attribute from a classified raster image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, select-by-attribute

I am trying to select just the black attribute (classified water in the image) but I can not select anything. In the attribute table it lets me select the row, but it will not select in the map. I just want the black attribute selected (*see image).

I do not know python at all.

[image]

Comment: The water class is actually Value 1/Count 8460. I just had the wrong one selected when I made the Snip.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it! Extract by Attribute (Spatial Analysis). Drag raster layer to input, and tell the "Where Clause" "Count" = 1 then click OK. Easy Peasy Lemon Squeezy!
BTW, I typed in Select Raster in the search bar.
Hope this helps others!!

Answer (score 0):

If the black 'water' attribute is the value "2" as it seems to be, you could reclassify the raster changing all other values (apart from 2) to null.  This would leave you with only the black raster.

What do you intend to do with the raster selection?

Comment: I'm doing a supervised classification, but using the unsupervised classification for water since it so accurately picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS the simplest tool to use would be [Con (Conditional)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000), which is specifically used for raster analysis. While selecting by attributes is not incorrect, attribute selection is more commonly applied to vector analysis where the tables tend to be more complex.